# Expression.Call "Contains" method throw "Ambiguous match found exception"

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

in .net core 2.1

this my code

```
//call class Expression 's method
public static MethodCallExpression Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, params Expression[] arguments);  
//service code
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x")
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "Name");
var value = Expression.Constant("xx");
var converted = Expression.Convert(value, property.Type);
var exp = Expression.Call(property, property.Type.GetMethod("Contains"), converted);

//then will throw Ambiguous match found exception
```

i found in .net core 2.1 has 4 mehods,in .net framework have 1 methos,how can i fix in .net core 2.1 ,run in .net framework it's ok

methods in .net core
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNcks.png

methods in .net framework
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTvEp.png

Comment: You have to specify method parameters as well, i.e what are the variables for your method

Comment: yes ,i specify method parameters ,the  "params Expression[] arguments" only one

Comment: No you are not specifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already noticed, there are multiple methods which match the name `Contains`. You are supposed to use the following [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Type___) of `GetMethod() which lets you specfiy the type parameters of the method.

```
var exp = Expression.Call(property, property.Type.GetMethod("Contains",/*Here you need the type parameters*/), converted);
```

Comment: thans ，it is my mistake